# conversion of ' to quote in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to write a lisp interpreter using only lisp primitive functions. I was writing my eval but I am not sure how I can detect the ' so I don't evaluate the symbol. I understand that 'x is converted to (quote x) internally, I fired up a lisp interpreter and tried the following:

```
(defun my-car (x) (car x)) 
(my-car (quote x)) -> QUOTE 
(my-car '(x)) -> QUOTE
(my-car 'x) -> Error: Attempt to take the car of A which is not listp.
```

I see that in the first two examples car detects the quote as being the first element and returns it, I am not sure why it doesn't do that in the last example though since essentially 'x should be converted to (quote x) then passed as an argument to my-car. I need to check for this for one of the base cases of my-eval so that if a quote precedes an atom I don't return its value. Is there a way to do that using only primitive functions?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using your own interpreter to evaluate that snippet? In Common Lisp the first and third should signal an error because the argument is a symbol, not a list, while the second should return `X`.

Answer (score 2):

Lisp evaluation happens in stages.

The first stage is the reader, which converts the text (sequence of characters) to *forms*, i. e. lists, symbols, and literal forms (characters, strings, numbers, arrays etc.).

The reader also converts `'` to a wrapped quote form around the following form (which may be a list, a symbol, etc.).  `'a` is *read* as `(quote a)`, `'(a)` is *read* as `(quote (a))`.

`Eval` then only needs a rule how to handle `quote` as an operator.  It never sees any `'`.

Answer (score 1):

Your lisp interpreter is not behaving like Common Lisp. You should get:

```
(defun my-car (x) (car x)) 
(my-car (quote x)) -> Error: Attempt to take the car of A which is not listp.
(my-car '(x)) -> X
(my-car 'x) -> Error: Attempt to take the car of A which is not listp.
(my-car (list 'QUOTE 'X)) -> QUOTE
(my-car ''x) -> QUOTE
(my-car (quote 'x)) -> QUOTE
(my-car '(quote x)) -> QUOTE
```

Step by step:

Source code:

```
(my-car ''x)
```

Parse:

```
(my-car (quote (quote x)))
```

Evaluate arguments

```
(#<Function MY-CAR> (quote x))
```

Call function:

```
X
```

This I because the car of the list of the symbol `QUOTE` and symbol `X` is `QUOTE`.